How do I restart the login request?
I'm trying to read data from here:
https://basedosdados.org/dataset/ff933265-8b61-4458-877a-173b3f38102b?table=74f616d0-933c-4198-9f8e-00858eff807d
The code doesn’t prompt for re-authentication, and I’ve even tried running this:
def limpar_variavel_de_ambiente():
    if "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in os.environ:
        del os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]

The first time I ran this, it asked me to log into my Google account:
bd.read_sql(query=query, billing_project_id=billing_id)
However, it has never asked again. Is there a way to delete the saved credential and force a new authentication? I’m not sure how to do this.
Thank you.

What happened after you logged in to your Google Account? Did it ask you to authorize something or to give permission to something? Did it say it was downloading something to your hard drive?

After running this:
bd.read_sql(query=query, billing_project_id=billing_id)
it asks me to log in to my Google account, and it downloaded the files from a query. However, the login prompt only happened the first time I ran the code, and I want it to happen every time.

What happens if you log out and/or clear your cookies?
